# Using a name like "John Doe" instead of the ID like "@johndoe1234" for YouTube comments

Tags: youtube

Is there any way to revert the names that appear in YouTube's comment section to the old style? I mean, it currently shows just `@[My Google ID]`, which is not so good, in my opinion, for people to remember and exposes my e-mail address.

Answer (score 1):

> #### Change your Handle
>
> A [handle](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/11585688) is a unique identifier that makes it easier for you to establish and maintain your distinct presence on YouTube.
>
> Note: You can change your handle twice within a 14-day period.
>
> 1. Sign in to [YouTube Studio](http://studio.youtube.com/).
> 2. From the left Menu, select **Customization** and then **Basic info**.
> 3. Under **Handle**, you can view or change your handle.
> 4. If you change your handle, click **PUBLISH** to confirm it.

Source:  [**Manage your YouTube channel's basic info**](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2657964?hl=en)

Answer (score -1):

You can change your display name on Youtube by following these steps:

1. When signed in, click on your avatar in the top-right corner.
2. Click “Settings” in the menus.
3. Next, click “Edit on Google” in the “Account” section.
4. There click “Name” and type your alternative first and last names.

Comment: Those are the old instructions. The new version doesn't have an "Edit on Google" option in the `Account` section.